# Ruby on Rails Routing error: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm currently working on a Rails project right now, doing learning and working on it at the same time...

So I was just trying to create a form for editing user and this is how I doing it

```
<%= form_for(@user,:url => { :action => "update",:controller => "users" }) do |f| %>
  <% @f = f %>
  <%= render 'users/dialog'%>
<% end %>
```

But then I got the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

Which I did not expect it to be happen since

```
<%= form_for(@user,:url => { :action => "create",:controller => "users" }) do |f| %>
```

is working for me.

Didn't find some answer I want on Google, hope someone can help me out on this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to supply a `:url` if you already pass the @user object.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'users/dialog'%>
<% end %>
```

Also, avoid setting variables such as `@f` in the view. This is not view's responsibility.